# Calculating distance between polygon and line using ArcGIS Desktop

Tags: arcgis-desktop, proximity

I’m trying to calculate the tax parcels distance closest to a transmission line.

- If the tax parcels distance to the transmission line is <2km, then I score 5.
- If 2-4km, score 4
- If 4-6km, score 3
- If 6-8km, score 2
- If >=8km, score 0

Which tool should I use to compute that?

I’m looking at building a suitability map in the end for best location for wind farms within a county.

Comment: Do you have Advanced license?

Comment: Are you using ArcGIS Pro or ArcMap?

Answer (score 0):

[Near (Analysis)](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/analysis-toolbox/near.htm) or [Generate Near Table](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/analysis-toolbox/generate-near-table.htm) then perform a series of selections/field calculations, or use [Calculate Field Code Blocks](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/calculate-field-examples.htm#ESRI_SECTION1_DF13F7EE4AF345CAAA46C1CFA2F7BFE1) to add your scoring.

From the docs:

> Near (Analysis) Calculates distances and other proximity information
> between features in one or more feature classes or layers. Unlike the
> Near tool, which modifies the input, Generate Near Table writes
> results to a new stand-alone table and supports finding more than one
> near feature.